# Asp.Net Core MVC, how to change the default login view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Got a project with authentication (store user-accounts in app), is there a way to change the default login-view?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More detail would have been appreciated. A question like this would generally be closed. However, I can make a few assumptions. You're using Identity, and specifically using `services.AddDefaultIdentity`. That means your login view you're wanting to customize is likely coming from the Default UI, and since there's no view in your actual project that corresponds to that, you're unclear how to change it. If all that is correct:

Identity now includes a Default UI, which is actually a Razor Class Library (RCL), so the views, static resources, etc. are all embedded in the library itself and added via the `AddDefaultUI` method (which is internally called by the `AddDefaultIdentity` method).

Based on the way RCLs work, anything physically in your project will override the same resource at the same location in the RCL. For the login view, that would be `Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Login.cshtml`. That's actually a Razor Page, so there's also a `Login.cshtml.cs` file in the same place, which is the codebehind. Theoretically, then, you can override by creating a Razor Page called `Login` in the same location in your project. However, more likely than not, you'd want to have that done for you automatically, which is where the scaffold comes in.

If you right-click on your project and go to Add > New Scaffolded Item..., there's an "Identity" tab with just a single scaffold listed. Choose that one, and you'll be presented with a dialog listing every Razor Page that's part of the Default UI RCL. You can choose one or all, and the page(s) will be added into your project at the right place to override those coming from the Default UI. Simply change the view in your project to your liking.

Unfortunately, the scaffold only covers Razor Pages, so things like static resources are not included. If you want to reference those, you'll need to look at the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Identity/UI/src) directly. You can also use the source to view the Razor Pages and add them to your project manually without the scaffold if you prefer.